# How to centre align the text in TextView and to avoid resizing when the content changes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a timer application for Android and I'm having a problem with TextView element which displays the minutes, seconds and milliseconds. I want to centre my text and at the same time to avoid the resizing of the view. The resizing happening each second so you can barely see the numbers because of the fast resizing of the field. That's happening because the char "1" doesn't have same with as "0" for example. I read about `android:gravity="center"`, but when I have `android:layout_width="260dp"` (fixed size), the string is still resizing. If I don't have `android:gravity="center"` and have fixed size, the content is aligned to left. In other words:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

*Fixed width with gravity - align at center but moving text

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="00:00:00"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

*Fixed size without gravity - fixed text but left aligned.
Thanks again.

Comment: do you have only one TextView in your layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Try programmatically setting a monospace font to make sure the width of the characters doesn't change:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have already loaded a custom font. 
`Typeface face;
        face = createFromAsset(getAssets(), "digital_counter_7.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(face);`

Comment: I see. Is there any way to make the font monospace? Otherwise it would really be easiest to use the default monospace font. Anyway, you're saying the "shaking" doesn't happen without gravity="center". What happens if you wrap the TextView in a layout having width="match_parent" and gravity="center" and use a fixed width for the TextView?

Comment: still shaking, the text is aligned to the centre but it still shaking.

Comment: Still shaking when no gravity specified inside the TextView? If so ... no more ideas, sorry :( Splitting, as suggested by @ArnavM (maybe even in 9 TextViews, 1 for each character), will be the only option left.

Answer (score 1):

use any monospaced external font. they have constant width for each character, so the string will not be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Split in 3 TextView(fixed width) and put in Linear/Relative Layout.

Comment: Mmmm, not so big deal. I prefer to stay left aligned that to split.

Comment: No, it won't, read my topic carefully. When I remove the `gravity`, the text is not shaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code:-

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```